# Alinhamento de texto css html

Tags: html, css

Como adaptar um texto sobre uma foto, onde ele irá começar no bottom da foto ou div e subindo conforme o tamanho?

exemplo abaixo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia explicar melhor o que você deseja, ficou um pouco vago...

Comment: o exemplo na foto está perfeito amigo

Comment: preciso que fique igual a foto 3

Comment: Poderia postar seu código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como a pergunta não tinha detalhamentos, criei um modelo a partir da imagem:

Crei uma `div` com a `class="pictureContainer"` e a atribui o seguinte estilo:

```
.pictureContainer{
  width: 400px; 
  height: auto; !important
  position: relative; !important
}
```

Dentro dessa div criei uma imagem com um `width: 100%`. E criei uma `div` com uma `class="pictureText"`, com este estilo:

```
.pictureContainer .pictureText{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute; !important
  bottom: 0; !important
}
```

E dentro dessa `div` criei um `p`:

```
.pictureContainer .pictureText p{
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute; !important
  bottom: 0; !important
  color: #fff;
}
```

É totalmente responsivo e proporcional, basta mudar o `width` da `div.pictureContainer` e o resto se adequará.

### Código completo

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.pictureContainer{
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.pictureContainer img{
  width: 100%;
}
.pictureContainer .pictureText{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.pictureContainer .pictureText p{
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="pictureContainer" >
  <img src="http://www.novosaplicativos.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/anonymous-isis-bitcoin-opisis.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="pictureText" >
  <p>Hacker descobre evidências de que os EUA teriam espaçonave de guerra.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo. OBrigado